# Creating collision in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i'm having a problem with my code. So, I want to create a game, in Pygame, where the bananas fall from the sky, and the monkey have to grab them. I'm having quite a hard time creating a collision between those two (spent hours trying already).

So, this is my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random, time, os
from pygame.locals import * 

#Variáveis necessárias
banana_speed = 5
monkey_speed = 20
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
pontos = 0
vidas = 3

#Nome do jogo
pygame.display.set_caption("Catch the fruit")

#Tamanho do ecrã do jogo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Macaco(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('monkey.png')
        self.rect = self.image
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 640 
    def keyboard(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += monkey_speed
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= monkey_speed
    def draw (self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.rect, (self.x, self.y))

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

class Banana(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('banana.png')
        self.rect = self.image
        self.x = random.randrange(0,WIDTH)
        self.y = -50
    def draw(self, screen):
        self.y = self.y + banana_speed
        screen.blit(self.rect,(self.x, self.y))

#Funções necessárias para o Loop
macaco = Macaco()
banana = Banana()
Background = Background('background.png', [0,0])

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

while vidas > 0:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.blit(Background.image, Background.rect)
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    macaco.keyboard()
    macaco.draw(screen)
    banana.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

edit:
So i'm trying another solution and did this:

```
import pygame, sys, random, time, os
from pygame.locals import * 

#Variáveis necessárias
banana_speed = 5
monkey_speed = 20
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
pontos = 0
vidas = 3
green = (0, 0 , 255)

#Nome do jogo
pygame.display.set_caption("Catch the fruit")

#Tamanho do ecrã do jogo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class Macaco(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = pygame.image.load('monkey.png')
        self.image = pygame.Surface([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 640
        self.image.fill(green)
    def keyboard(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += monkey_speed
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= monkey_speed
    def draw (self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.rect, (self.x, self.y))

class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location

class Banana(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = pygame.image.load('banana.png')
        self.image = pygame.Surface([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
        self.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH)
        self.y = -50
    def draw(self, screen):
        self.y = self.y + banana_speed
        screen.blit(self.rect,(self.x, self.y))


#Funções necessárias para o Loop
macaco = Macaco()
banana = Banana()
Background = Background('background.png', [0,0])

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

while vidas > 0:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.blit(Background.image, Background.rect)
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    macaco.keyboard()
    macaco.draw(screen)
    banana.draw(screen)
    blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(macaco, banana, True)
    for blocks in blocks_hit_list:
        pontos +=1
    pygame.display.update()
```

Could you give me some help please?

Comment: Er... coalition? Do you mean a **collision**?

Comment: Yea that, sorry my mistake

Comment: Are you already familiar with [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)? What have you tried yet?

Comment: Trying that right now... Still nothing :(

Comment: There's a good introduction to sprites and sprite groups in [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_sprites&lang=de#section_13). Keep in mind that you have to update the rects of the sprites if you want to use them for collision detection.

Comment: Update? How? I don't have any idea on what's wrong with my programm

Comment: I'll post a short example (although I think there are countless similar questions on SO). To update the position of a rect you can just set its `center` or `topleft` (or other) attributes to the new position, e.g. `self.rect.center = self.x, self.y`.

Comment: Wouldn't that be bad for me? Since I want to add falling bananas on a moving monkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created two sprite groups: `all_sprites` which contains all sprites and is used to update and draw them with just two lines of code, and the `bananas` group which is used to check for collisions between the macaco and the bananas. Then we need the [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) function to get the collided sprites. You have to pass a sprite instance and a sprite group and it'll check for you if the sprite has collided with the sprites in the group. It returns the collided bananas as a list over which you can iterate to do something with them or for example to increment a points counter.

You have to call the `__init__` method of the parent class in your sprites to be able to use them correctly with sprite groups (do that with the `super` function `super().__init__()` (in Python 2 `super(Macaco, self).__init__()`).

To update the positions of your sprites, set their `topleft` (or `center`) attribute to the new x, y coordinates.

To get a rect from an image call `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`.

```
import sys
import random
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))


class Macaco(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill((190, 140, 20))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = 300
        self.y = 640
        self.speed = 20

    def keyboard(self, keys):
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y


class Banana(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill((230, 230, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 770)
        self.y = -50
        self.speed = 5

    def update(self):
        self.y += self.speed
        self.rect.topleft = self.x, self.y


macaco = Macaco()
banana = Banana()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(macaco, banana)
bananas = pygame.sprite.Group(banana)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    macaco.keyboard(keys)
    all_sprites.update()
    # Collision detection. Check if macaco collided with bananas group,
    # return collided bananas as a list. dokill argument is True, so
    # that collided bananas will be deleted.
    collided_bananas = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(macaco, bananas, True)
    for collided_banana in collided_bananas:
        print('Collision.')

    screen.fill((70, 40, 70))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what i was missing then... You helped me a lot!